# Load project's mp3 into MPMediaItem

Tags: ios, audio, mpmediaitem

I've got an mp3 in my project's "Supporting Files" folder, and I'd like to create an MPMediaItem for that song. Normally, I'd use `MPMediaQuery` if I were creating an MPMediaItem from the user's library, but I'm not sure how that would work with a project file.  Any pointers would be terrific. Thanks for reading!